# How do higher-order optical chiralities look like?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, conservation-laws, chirality

The optical chirality of the electromagnetic field is a conserved quantity, analogous to the energy density, linear momentum density, and angular momentum density, which describes how chiral the EM field is at each point, and it is given by
$$
C=\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}\mathbf E\cdot\left(\nabla\times\mathbf E\right)+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\mathbf B\cdot\left(\nabla\times\mathbf B\right).
$$
It is a time-even pseudoscalar, which puts it in a nice little niche of its own. It was originally discovered by Lipkin [[*J. Math. Phys.* **5**, 696 (1964)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1704165)], who called it "zilch" for lack of a better name, and it was rediscovered and put to good use recently by Tang and Cohen [[*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **104**, 163901 (2010)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.163901)], who showed that in the linear regime and the magnetic dipole approximation, all chiral interactions of a molecule with the electromagnetic field produce effects proportional to the optical chirality $C$ times a molecular chirality.

Lipkin himself inscribed $C$ as a component of a bigger tensor, $Z^{\lambda\mu}_{\ \ \ \ \nu}$, and Kibble extended it shortly thereafter [[*J. Math. Phys.* **6**, 1022 (1965)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1704363)] into an infinite series of related conservation laws. That is, the optical chirality $C$ is really the first term in a hierarchy of measures of chirality, somewhat reminiscent of a multipole expansion.

This hierarchy was systematized fairly recently by Anco and Pohjanpelto [[*Acta Appl. Math.* **69**, 285 (2001)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1014263903283)]; they provide a completeness result so it seems that any relevant conservation law must be contained within their scheme. Anco and Pohjanpelto also point to the previous work by Fushchich and Nikitin [*Symmetries of Equations of Quantum Mechanics* (Allerton Press, New York, 1994), pp 288-296; [eprint](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/P_Physics/PQm_Quantum%20mechanics/Fushchich,%20Nikitin.%20Symmetry%20of%20equations%20of%20quantum%20mechanics(478s).pdf)] who provide a complete classification, I believe, in relatively more readable terms.

---

I am studying a field configuration which I believe to be chiral, but it turns out that the optical chirality $C$ vanishes identically for it. This is, by itself, not fatal: the electric field of a static, chiral configuration of charges is also in general chiral, but for it $C$ vanishes as well. As Tang and Cohen point out, in these cases there is (or ought to be) a hierarchy of higher-order time-even pseudoscalar optical chiralities, which can in general pick out chiral components given by higher-order derivatives of the electric and magnetic fields.

**I am looking for the first few terms in this hierarchy.** That is, I am looking for time-even pseudoscalar conserved quantities, involving higher order derivatives, in the first few rungs of this ladder. Moreover, I am looking for explicit expressions in terms of the electric and magnetic field vectors.

I must confess, however, that I find Anco and Pohjanpelto's work to be pretty heavy going, and particularly I am finding the Killing vector language pretty deadly. That is: I roughly understand what's going on, but I am having trouble implementing the relations they describe to obtain concrete examples. (Which means, of course, that I don't actually understand what's going on all that well.) I find the classification by Fushchich and Nikitin more accessible but I am still struggling to find expressions I am confident about, and I'm pretty lost as to how one would look for the first nontrivial time-even pseudoscalar beyond the terms they explicitly enumerate.

I am therefore hoping someone more fluent with this sort of language will have an easier time decoding these things. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Related question on this hierarchy: [Optical chirality and its possible hierarchy of generalizations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111486/).

Comment: Please, see the following recent review by T.G. Philibin where the conserved quantities generalizing  the zilch are given in equations (21-22). These quantities correspond to the Noether symmetries given in equation (19).
http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0687

Comment: @David Yeah, we've seen that one, but I hadn't made it that far in - you're right, it does include the quantities of interest. See also [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223991) and [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32904/) for where we are at the moment. It's a bit curious that Philbin doesn't discuss the rest of the components of the zilch tensor but for this question indeed it's only the 000...0 components that matter. We found [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/14/12/123019) by Cameron and Barnett most useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over the days I've had an extensive discussion with Emilio and ACuriousMind in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32904/chiral-crap). There, we discussed a bunch of issues related to this question and [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/223991/what-symmetry-is-associated-with-conservation-of-lipkins-zilch) by Emilio. In my recent answer to the latter, I laid out much of the fundamental ideas that I will be using in this answer. Thus, I refer back to it for most of the background. I furthermore note that this answer is not the only way to approach the question: A related yet distinct approach was outlined [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0687v3), as pointed out in the comments on the question.

### The basic setup

The zilch tensor is related to *duality rotations* (which are just rotations on the vector $(F_{\mu\nu},{*F}_{\mu\nu})$ in electromagnetism, which are a symmetry of Maxwell's equations:

$$ \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0 \qquad \qquad \partial_\mu {*F}^{\mu\nu}=0$$

but regrettably not of the standard action for electrodynamics:

$$ S_\text{Maxwell}=-\frac{1}{4}\int\mathrm d^4x F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} $$

One nice way of getting rid of this problem is introduced in the answer I linked earlier, and can be summarized as follows: Treat $F_{\mu\nu}$ and its dual as independent variables in the action (for notational clarity, we introduce $G^{\mu\nu}\equiv *F^{\mu\nu}$, but keep in the back of your mind the *constraint*, which we can impose on all equations we derive, that they are each other's duals. This leads one to consider a modified action

$$S_{\text{duality}}=-\frac{1}{8}\int \mathrm d^4x F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+G_{\mu\nu}G^{\mu\nu} $$

Along with $G^{\mu\nu}$ (which, again, is really just the dual field strength tensor *in disguise*), we introduce a dual (electric) four-potential $C^\mu$ such that $G_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{[\mu}C_{\nu]}$.

### Symmetries

The new action and associated Lagrangian $\mathcal L$ are not only nice because they are manifestly invariant under *duality rotations* (since $F$ and $G$ appear completely symmetrically). In fact, it generally reflects the symmetries of Maxwell's equations better than the standard Maxwell Lagrangian. To clarify this remark, we note the following:

Consider a general transformation of the fundamental fields underlying the Lagrangian:

$$ A^\mu\mapsto A'^\mu=A^\mu+\delta A^\mu 
\qquad \qquad C^\mu\mapsto C'^\mu=C^\mu+\delta C^\mu $$

(where we must always ensure that the variation does not violate the constraint $G_{\mu\nu}\equiv {*F}_{\mu\nu}$). Inserting this into the Lagrangian and using $F_{\mu\nu}\delta F^{\mu\nu}=-{*F}_{\mu\nu} \: \delta {*F}^{\mu\nu}$, we find:

$$\delta \mathcal L\propto \delta G_{\mu\nu}(G'^{\mu\nu}-{*F}'^{\mu\nu}) $$

which precisely vanishes whenever we remain on the constraint surface. Hence, a transformation that does not violate the constraint induces a symmetry of the action and hence of Maxwell's equations, and also gives rise to a conserved current through Noether's theorem. As we saw, this includes transformations that do *not* correspond to symmetries of the Maxwell action. To derive the general expression for a Noether current, we perform the standard derivation (using derivatives of $\mathcal L$) and obtain:

$$\tag{$\star$} \delta \mathcal L = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\nu (F^{\mu\nu}\delta A_\mu+ G^{\mu\nu}\delta C_\mu) $$

### Infinite hierarchies

Now, we are in a position to finally determine the infinite hierarchy of symmetries of Maxwell's equations that includes the zilch tensor $Z^\mu_{\ \ \nu\rho}$ as a special case. We start from the basic duality rotation:

$$ \delta A_\mu = -\theta C_\mu \qquad \qquad \delta C_\mu = \theta A_\mu $$

Using our general formula ($\star$), we find:

$$\delta \mathcal L = \frac{\theta}{2}\partial_\nu(-F^{\mu\nu}C_\mu + G^{\mu\nu}A_\mu)\equiv 0 $$

and hence obtain a conserved current

$$ \kappa^\nu=G^{\mu\nu}A_\mu - F^{\mu\nu}C_\mu $$

Now, the crucial insight is that we can easily generalize this procedure to generate new conserved currents with more indices. On the level of field strengths, the duality rotation induces a variation

$$ \delta F_{\mu\nu}=-\theta G_{\mu\nu} \qquad\qquad \delta G_{\mu\nu}=\theta F_{\mu\nu} $$

Now, it is not *that* far-fetched to look for a related current which induces a similar variation

$$ \delta F_{\mu\nu}=-\zeta^\alpha \partial_\alpha G_{\mu\nu} \qquad \qquad 
\delta G_{\mu\nu}= \zeta^\alpha\partial_\alpha F_{\mu\nu} $$

instead. It is easy to check that this variation is induced by the following variation of the potentials:

$$\delta A_\mu=-\zeta^\alpha \partial_\alpha C_\mu \qquad \qquad \delta C_\mu = \zeta^\alpha \partial_\alpha A_\mu $$

We note that, once again, the transformed $F'$ and $G'$ satisfy the equations of motion (as is easily checked by using the equations of motion for the old field strengths and the fact that partial derivatives commute). We can see a pattern beginning to emerge here, which easily generalizes to yield the infinite hierarchy of symmetries that was alluded to in the question! The variation of $F_{\mu\nu}$ (and $G_{\mu\nu}$) is of the same form as the variation of the corresponding potential, after replacing $A$ ($C$) by $F$ ($G$). Thus, we can consider a variation of the more general form

$$\delta A_\mu=-\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_n} C_\mu \qquad \qquad 
\delta C_\mu=\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_n} A_\mu$$

which induces a variation on the level of field strengths of the form:

$$\delta F_{\mu\nu}=-\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_n} G_{\mu\nu} 
\qquad \qquad 
\delta G_{\mu\nu}=\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_n} F_{\mu\nu}$$
which will clearly give rise to an infinite hierarchy of conserved currents. We note, as a side remark, that $\xi$ will automatically be symmetric in all of its indices (because of the derivatives that it is contracted with).

*However*, there is a problem with this idea because the current, given by ($\star$), will not be gauge invariant (one can see that $A$ and $C$ will appear explicitly, and this is typically a bad sign!). Fortunately, this is not the only way to induce the above variation of the field strength tensors. One can alternatively consider variations of the following form:

$$ \delta A_\mu=-\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}} G_{\alpha_n \mu} \qquad \qquad 
\delta C_\mu=\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}} F_{\alpha_n \mu}$$

It is clear that the Noether current corresponding to this variation will, in fact, only feature $F$ and $G$ and hence it will be gauge-invariant. A quick check shows that, indeed, the variation of the field strength is identical:

$$\delta F_{\mu\nu}=-\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n} \partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}(\partial_\mu G_{\alpha_n \nu}-\partial_\nu G_{\alpha_n\mu})
= -\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n} \partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}\partial_{\alpha_n}G_{\mu\nu} $$

where we expanded $G_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of $C_\mu$ to perform the last step. Of course, the variation of $G_{\mu\nu}$ is similarly checked. However, that is not all!

As explained in [the paper by Cameron & Barnett linked in my afore-mentioned answer](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/14/12/123019) (on which this answer is based!), one can obtain *another* infinite sequence of symmetries, by considering variations

$$\delta A_\mu=\kappa^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}} F_{\alpha_n \mu} \qquad \qquad 
\delta C_\mu=\kappa^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}} G_{\alpha_n \mu} $$

which again generate symmetries of the equations of motion, as can be seen from

$$\delta F_{\mu\nu}=\kappa^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n} \partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}(\partial_\mu F_{\alpha_n \nu}-\partial_\nu F_{\alpha_n\mu})
= \kappa^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n} \partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}\partial_{\alpha_n}F_{\mu\nu} $$

### Conserved quantities

Now, we can proceed with the investigation of our gauge-invariant currents. It is easily seen from ($\star$) that our first infinite chain of symmetries gives rise to

$$\delta \mathcal L=\frac{\xi^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}}{2}\partial_\nu
(G^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}F_{\alpha_n \mu}
-F^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}G_{\alpha_n \mu}) $$

whence we conclude that we have the following infinite sequence of  conserved currents:

$$ Z^\nu_{\ \ \alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n}:=
G^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}F_{\alpha_n \mu}
-F^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}G_{\alpha_n \mu}$$

Furthermore, our second sequence yields:

$$\delta \mathcal L=\frac{\kappa^{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}}{2}\partial_\nu
(F^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}F_{\alpha_n \mu}
+G^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}G_{\alpha_n \mu}) $$

which corresponds to the "ladder" of conserved quantities

$$\tau^\nu_{\ \ \alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}:=
F^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}F_{\alpha_n \mu}
+G^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_{n-1}}G_{\alpha_n \mu} $$

Without derivation, we note that the ladders of $Z$ and $\tau$-tensors are dual to each other in some sense: We define conserved  charges through the usual method, i.e.

$$ Q^Z_{\alpha_1\cdots \alpha_n}:= \int \mathrm d^3 x Z^0_{\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n} $$

and similarly for $\tau$-tensors. For the case $n=1$ it turns out that the corresponding $Z$-tensor defines a conserved charge that vanishes identically, while the $\tau$-charges are nontrivial. However, for the case $n=2$ the situation is reversed: The charges defined by the $\tau$-tensor are trivial, but the "partner" $Z$-tensor is of considerably more interest. It is given by

$$ Z^\nu_{\alpha\beta}={*F}^{\mu\nu}\partial_\alpha F_{\beta\mu} - F^{\mu\nu}\partial_\alpha {*F}_{\beta\mu}$$

which we can immediately identify with the *zilch tensor* mentioned in the question. The corresponding conserved charges are non-trivial, with the best-known example being:

\begin{align*} Q^Z_{00}&=\int \mathrm d^3 x Z^0_{\ \ 00} =\int \mathrm d^3 x \ {*F}^{i0}\partial_0 F_{0i}
- F^{i0}\partial_0 {*F}_{0i}\\
&=\int \mathrm d^3x \vec E\cdot (\vec \nabla\times \vec E)
+\vec B \cdot (\vec \nabla\times \vec B)=\int \mathrm d^3x C
\end{align*}

where we used Maxwell's equations in the vacuum to convert time derivatives into curls. the integral of the optical chirality $C$ (note that I have set $c=\epsilon_0=1$ throughout). The general pattern is the following: For even (odd) $n$, the $Z$-tensor ($\tau$-tensor) defines a non-trivial charge while its partner defines a trivial one. All the non-trivial charges thus obtained are argued, in the paper by Cameron & Barnett, to admit an interpretation in terms of "the difference *[(for $Z$-charges)]* and sum *[(for $\tau$-charges)]* of photon numbers of opposite circular polarization". This is yet another piece of evidence that the conserved $Z$-tensors yield information about the chirality of the system under consideration.

Given all of this, it is not too hard to find the next possible time-even, pseudo-scalar conserved chiral quantities from the ladder of $Z$-charges: We consider the cases $n=4,6$, with corresponding non-trivial charge densities:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal Q^Z_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} &=Z^0_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} 
= G^{0i}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu\partial_\rho F_{\sigma i}
-F^{0i}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\partial_\rho G_{\sigma i}\\
\mathcal Q^Z_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma\kappa\lambda} &=Z^0_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma\kappa\lambda} 
= G^{0i}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu\partial_\rho\partial_\kappa\partial_\lambda F_{\sigma i}
-F^{0i}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\partial_\rho \partial_\kappa\partial_\lambda G_{\sigma i}
\end{align*}

Luckily, we do not have to consider many components of these tensors: We are only interested in *pseudoscalar* quantities, and hence we must impose that all free indices equal $0$ (else we will get a quantity that transforms like a vector or tensor under $O(3)$). We furthemore note that we do not lose anything by only considering $Z$-charges here, since the non-trivial $\tau$-charges (which occur when $n=3,5$) will have an odd number of time-derivatives: They cannot be time-even!

Hence, the first two local quantities of interest (after the optical chirality $C$), arising from the constructed hierarchy of conserved chiral quantities, are:

\begin{align*}
C^{(2)}&:= \mathcal Q^Z_{0000} 
= G^{0i}\partial_0^3 F_{0 i}
-F^{0i}\partial_0^3 G_{0 i}\\
C^{(3)}&:=\mathcal Q^Z_{000000} 
= G^{0i}\partial_0^5 F_{0 i}
-F^{0i}\partial_0^5 G_{0i}
\end{align*}

which can be written in terms of the electric and magnetic fields as:

\begin{align*}
C^{(i+1)}&=\vec B \cdot (\partial_0^2)^i(\vec\nabla \times\vec B)+\vec E \cdot (\partial_0^2)^i(\vec\nabla\times\vec E)
\end{align*}

This formula is easily seen to generalize to all integers $i\geq 0$.